# how to create and pass rdf graphs from memory to DOTNETRDF

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantics, dotnetrdf

If I have RDF Triples say that they are held in Redis as Hash Key where each triple is represented as Key : S:Value P:Value O:Value.

How to pass collection of such triples to the DOTNETRDF and represent them as graph so that I can run SPARQL Queries on them ?

I do understand that SPARQL Engine in DOTNETRDF can operate on stores only , but if I create a class that implement IGraph Interface , then its possible to run the SPARQL Queries on the triples

Comment: "I am stuck with this problem since one week ." If you've been working on this for a week, there certainly should be some attempts that you've already tried, and you should have a more specific technical problem to address by now.  What have you tried during this week?  What hasn't worked?  What helped?

Comment: @Joshua Taylor , thanks for your response . In fact I tried to implement the IGraph interface in way I defined a data structure for passing the triples , but it seems that the only way to apply sparql engine is by storing these triples in a triple store . the current in-memory triple stores provided by DOTNETRDF have many limitations , and I dag so much the google but couldnt find any good resources about how to build my own triple store and integrate it with DOTNETRDF . so I really appreciate experts opinions about this problem

Comment: the original context question was : is it possible to run the SPARQL Queries on the triples directly if they are passed to the DOTNETRDF API as an IGraph ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In fact I tried to implement the IGraph interface in way I defined a data structure for passing the triples , but it seems that the only way to apply sparql engine is by storing these triples in a triple store

You can put any `IGraph` implementation in the standard `TripleStore` instance so implementing `IGraph` is sufficient to get you started.  It is generally easiest to extend from `BaseGraph` if you aren't already as that will give you a lot of implementation for free.

So yes you can run queries on an arbitrary `IGraph` implementation:

```
IGraph g = new MyCustomGraph();
TripleStore store = new TripleStore();
store.Add(g);

// Run query on the store as normal
```

However if you want to integrate more deeply then you need to look at implementing the `ISparqlDataset` interface which is the actual interface used internally by the query engine (`IGraph` and `ITripleStore` end up wrapped inside this).  Again there are base implementations like [`BaseDataset`](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/index.asp?Topic=VDS.RDF.Query.Datasets.BaseDataset) and  [`BaseQuadDataset`](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/index.asp?Topic=VDS.RDF.Query.Datasets.BaseQuadDataset) which will give you chunks of the implementation.

You may want to look at the open source [BrightstarDB](https://github.com/BrightstarDB/BrightstarDB/tree/develop/src/core/BrightstarDB/Query) for an existing example of another triple store that uses dotNetRDF's SPARQL engine

Comment: thank you for your reply , its working for me but can you please provide me with an example of any custom graph ??